# Fast Cosine Transform via FFT

Tags: fft, python, dct

I want to implement the Fast Cosine Transform. I read on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform#Computation), that there is a fast version of the DCT which is similarly computed to the FFT. I tried to read the cited [Makhoul](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=1163351)* paper, for the FTPACK and FFTW implementations that are also used in [Scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.dct.html), but I were not able to extract the actually algorithm. This is what I have so far:

FFT code:

```
def fft(x):
    if x.size ==1:
        return x
    N = x.size
    x0 = my_fft(x[0:N:2])
    x1 = my_fft(x[0+1:N:2])
    k = numpy.arange(N/2)
    e = numpy.exp(-2j*numpy.pi*k/N)
    l = x0 + x1 * e
    r = x0 - x1 * e  
    return numpy.hstack([l,r])
```

DCT code:

```
def dct(x):
    k = 0
    N = x.size
    xk = numpy.zeros(N)
    for k in range(N):     
        for n in range(N):
            xn = x[n]
            xk[k] += xn*numpy.cos(numpy.pi/N*(n+1/2.0)*k)
    return xk
```

FCT trial:

```
def my_fct(x):
    if x.size ==1:
        return x
    N = x.size
    x0 = my_fct(x[0:N:2]) # have to be set to zero?
    x1 = my_fct(x[0+1:N:2])
    k = numpy.arange(N/2)
    n = # ???
    c = numpy.cos(numpy.pi/N*(n+1/2.0)*k)
    l = x0 #???
    r = x0 #???
    return numpy.hstack([l,r])
```

*J. Makhoul, "A fast cosine transform in one and two dimensions," IEEE Trans. Acoust. Speech Sig. Proc. 28 (1), 27-34 (1980).

Comment: Are you asking if your DCT code is correct or something?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I added another sentence in the beginning. My aim is to implement the FCT on basis of the FFT.

Comment: The IDCT is given at [Computation of the Inverse DCT (IDCT) Using DCT Or IFFT](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/51311).

Answer (score 31):

I've been reading about this and there are multiple ways to do it, using different size N.  My Matlab is rusty, so here they are in Python (`N` is length of input signal `x`, `k` is `arange(N)` = $[0, 1, 2, ..., N-1]$):

### Type 2 DCT using 4N FFT and no shifts

Signal `[a, b, c, d]` becomes

`[0, a, 0, b, 0,  c,  0,  d,  0,  d,  0,  c, 0, b, 0, a]`.

Then take the FFT to get the spectrum

`[A, B, C, D, 0, -D, -C, -B, -A, -B, -C, -D, 0, D, C, B]`

then throw away everything but the first `[A, B, C, D]`, and you're done:

```
u = zeros(4 * N)
u[1:2*N:2] = x
u[2*N+1::2] = x[::-1]

U = fft(u)[:N]
return U.real
```

### Type 2 DCT using 2N FFT mirrored (Makhoul)

`[a, b, c, d]` becomes `[a, b, c, d, d, c, b, a]`.  Take the FFT of that to get
`[A, B, C, D, 0, D*, C*, B*]`, then throw away everything but `[A, B, C, D]` and multiply it by $e^{-j \pi k \over 2 N}$ ([half-sample shift](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/10250/29)) to get the DCT:

```
y = empty(2*N)
y[:N] = x
y[N:] = x[::-1]

Y = fft(y)[:N]

Y *= exp(-1j*pi*k/(2*N))
return Y.real
```

### Type 2 DCT using 2N FFT padded (Makhoul)

`[a, b, c, d]` becomes `[a, b, c, d, 0, 0, 0, 0]`.  Take the FFT of that to get
`[A, B, C, D, E, D*, C*, B*]`, then throw away everything but `[A, B, C, D]` and multiply it by $2e^{-j \pi k \over 2 N}$ to get the DCT:

```
y = zeros(2*N)
y[:N] = x

Y = fft(y)[:N]

Y *= 2 * exp(-1j*pi*k/(2*N))
return Y.real
```

### Type 2 DCT using N FFT (Makhoul)

Signal `[a, b, c, d, e, f]` becomes `[a, c, e, f, d, b]`, then take the FFT to get `[A, B, C, D, C*, B*]`.  Multiply by $2 e^{-j \pi k \over 2N}$ and then take the real part:

```
v = empty_like(x)
v[:(N-1)//2+1] = x[::2]

if N % 2: # odd length
    v[(N-1)//2+1:] = x[-2::-2]
else: # even length
    v[(N-1)//2+1:] = x[::-2]

V = fft(v)

V *= 2 * exp(-1j*pi*k/(2*N))
return V.real
```

On my machine, these are all roughly the same speed, since generating `exp(-1j*pi*k/(2*N))` takes longer than the FFT.  :D

```
In [99]: timeit dct2_4nfft(a)
10 loops, best of 3: 23.6 ms per loop

In [100]: timeit dct2_2nfft_1(a)
10 loops, best of 3: 20.1 ms per loop

In [101]: timeit dct2_2nfft_2(a)
10 loops, best of 3: 20.8 ms per loop

In [102]: timeit dct2_nfft(a)
100 loops, best of 3: 16.4 ms per loop

In [103]: timeit scipy.fftpack.dct(a, 2)
100 loops, best of 3: 3 ms per loop
```

Comment: Great answer, helped with my implementation a lot! Additional note: The last method "Type 2 DCT using N FFT" still works properly if the signal length is odd; the last element moves to the middle element. I have verified the math and code for this fact.

Comment: @Nayuki Are you generating `exp(-1j*pi*k/(2*N))` or is there a shortcut to that step?

Comment: I am generating `exp(-1j*pi*k/(2*N))` in my [code](https://www.nayuki.io/res/fast-discrete-cosine-transform-algorithms/fastdctfft.py), because a quarter-sample shift is necessary to make the DCT-to-DFT mapping work. What makes you ask?

Comment: Hi, how would this work for the Type III DCT, to compute the inverse of the DCT-II?

Comment: `Type 2 DCT using 2N FFT mirrored (Makhoul)` is the way to go for `2D`.

Comment: Reading this again, on the `Type 2 DCT using N FFT (Makhoul)` we have `[a, b, c, d, e, f]` on the input, but the output there is no `e, f` samples. In other words, the input is size `6`, and the output is size `4`. Where `e, f` would como from?

Comment: @EduardoReis I think it's for real input only

Comment: Just noticed that `[A, B, C, D, C*, B*]` is representing the output of the `FFT`, and not the output of the `DCT`. That was the root of the entire confusion in my thoughts.

Comment: I keep coming back to this post, really useful! BTW What was the size of `a` when timing the different approaches???

Comment: @EduardoReis I don't know what `a` was, you'll have to run your own tests :)

Comment: I wonder if you could consider answering this [related question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/74949/57249) calling for a step-by-step "manual" calculation of a single coefficient of a 2 x 2 matrix to match the Makhoul Python formula. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure what method the paper you referenced uses, but I have derived this before and here is what I ended up with: (Assuming $x(n)$ is the input)

let

$y(n) = \Bigl\lbrace 
\begin{array}{ll}
x(n), & n=0,1,...,N-1\\
x(2N - 1 - n), & n=N,N+1,...,2N-1
\end{array}$

The DCT is then given by

$C(k) = \mathrm{Re}\Bigl\lbrace e^{-j\pi \frac{k}{2N}} FFT\lbrace y(n)\rbrace\Bigr\rbrace$

So you basically create the $2N$ length sequence $y(n)$ where the first half is $x(n)$ and the second half is $x(n)$ reversed.  Then just take the FFT and multiply that vector by a phase ramp.  Finally take only the real part and you have the DCT.

Here's the code in MATLAB.

```
function C = fdct(x)
    N = length(x);
    y = zeros(1,2*N);
    y(1:N) = x;
    y(N+1:2*N) = fliplr(x);
    Y = fft(y);
    k=0:N-1;
    C = real(exp(-j.* pi.*k./(2*N)).*Y(1:N));
```

**Edit:**

Note: The DCT formula this is using is:

$C(k) = 2\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x(n) \cos\left(\frac{\pi k}{2N}(2n+1) \right)$

There are several ways of scaling the summation so it may not match up exactly with other implementations.  For instance, MATLAB uses:

$C(k) = w(k)\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x(n) \cos\left(\frac{\pi k}{2N}(2n+1) \right)$

where $w(0) = \sqrt\frac{1}{N}$ and $w(1...N-1) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{N}}$

You can account for this by properly scaling the output.

Comment: y(n) is supposed to be N-length, not 2N-length.  That's how you get the 4x computation speed, by calculating N-length DCT from N-length signal instead of 2N FFT from 2N signal. http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e161/lectures/dct/node2.html http://www-ee.uta.edu/dip/Courses/EE5355/Discrete%20class%201.pdf

Answer (score 2):

For true scientific computing, the amount of memory usage is important too.
Therefore the N point FFT is more attractive to me. This is only possible due to Hermitian Symmetry of the signal.
The reference Makhoul is given here. And actually has the algorithm for calculating DCT and IDCT or DCT10 and DCT01.
http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/1163351/

Answer (score 1):

I wrote python numpy/scipy functions for DCT and DST, this can be usefull if you want to use it with autodiff libraries like pytorch that have differentiable FFT but not DCT and DST (yet).

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.fftpack

def dct_with_fft(x):
    N = x.size
    v = np.empty_like(x)
    v[:(N-1)//2+1] = x[::2]

    if N % 2: # odd length
        v[(N-1)//2+1:] = x[-2::-2]
    else: # even length
        v[(N-1)//2+1:] = x[::-2]

    V = scipy.fftpack.fft(v)

    k = np.arange(N)
    V *= 2 * np.exp(-1j*np.pi*k/(2*N))
    return V.real


def dst_with_fft(x):
    N = x.size
    v = np.empty_like(x)
    v[:(N-1)//2+1] = x[::2]

    if N % 2: # odd length
        v[(N-1)//2+1:] = -x[-2::-2]
    else: # even length
        v[(N-1)//2+1:] = -x[::-2]

    V = scipy.fftpack.fft(1j*v)

    k = np.arange(N)
    V *= 2 * np.exp(-1j*np.pi*k/(2*N))
    return V.imag[::-1]

N = 5
x = np.random.rand(N)

print(dct_with_fft(x))
print(scipy.fft.dct(x))

print(dst_with_fft(x))
print(scipy.fft.dst(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Beautiful! "Type 2 DCT using N FFT (Makhoul)" with considering "DCT scaling" is my favorite.

```
%dct via fft N-point
N = 4;
n = (0:1:(N-1))
k = (0:1:(N-1))
a    = [1 2 3 4]
a_oe = [1 3 4 2]
Afft = fft(a_oe)
W = 1*exp(-1i*1*pi*(k)/(2*N))
for i = 1:1:N
    if i == 1
        W(i) = W(i)*sqrt(1/N);
    else
        W(i) = W(i)*sqrt(2/N);
    end
end

A = W .* Afft
A = real(A)
check = A - dct(a) %should be all zero if correct
```