# How to iplement fast DCT-III (for inverse of DCT-II) using FFT or iFFT

Tags: fft, ifft, dct

I have to implement DCT-II and its inverse which is equivalently given by a forward DCT-III. All from real to real.

I have been checking some paper where it is specified how to do it. However, I already have kissfft as a dependency so I can use FFT and iFFT. I have implemented DCT-II using FFT and an extra space of 4N. I found three different ways to do it [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2807/fast-cosine-transform-via-fft).

For DCT-III, I wounder if I can do the inverse in a clever way (as in the last link) or if I have to implement it using the [formula](http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e161/lectures/dct/node2.html).

Comment: Look for Chen 1977 famous paper that describes and explicitly shows a fast DCT-II and its inverse for N=8,16, etc...

Comment: You can find the answer in: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2807/fast-cosine-transform-via-fft