# Retrieve DFT coefficients from DCT coefficients

Tags: matlab, fft, dft, dct

A vector `a` is transformed via a discrete cosine transform (DCT) to give vector `b`. For example in Matlab

`b=dct(a);`.

Vector `a` is also transformed via a discrete Fourier transform (DFT) to give vector `c`. E.g.

`c=fft(a);`

What is the fastest way to determine `c` from `b` without using `a` or retrieving it? For example,

`c=fft(idft(b));`

is not allowed.

Comment: Is this a homework question? And, what do you mean by "fastest"?

Comment: @MBaz Not a homework question. I've been reading around calculating a DCT using an FFT (e.g. https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/10606) and was interested in the ability to directly transform between the two domains.

I guess "fastest" is in the eye of the beholder. Lets go for a big-O style metric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Behind an FFT or a DCT operator, which can be implemented as a matrix product. Depending on the shape of your discrete vectors, you may have  $b=D\times a$ and  $c=F\times a$. So you can find your answer with a suitable matrix product. You can also find fast algorithms by decomposing each of the above matrices in simpler matrix product, or using lifting-like implementation. The very fastest can be more difficult to find.

Comment: Thank you for this. Could you expand on the lifting approach? My understanding is that lifting is primarily useful for solving non-linear problems but I'm unsure as to how it might be used to speed up this operation?

Comment: Lifting is indeed a term with many meaning in different fields. A lifting scheme for filter banks (applicable to DFT, DCT) is a technique to better interleave "filter taps" and "subsampling", allowing faster operations, and also the introduction of (useful) non-linearities

Comment: Cool, thanks, I'll check it out.