# How can extract the cosine transform formula used for 2D by scipy.fft.dct

Tags: python, dct, 2d

For the 1D cosine transform the documentation is clear in [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fft.dct.html), and I can reproduce it easily:

The formula is:

$$y_k= 2 \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x_n \cos \left( \frac{\pi k(2n + 1)}{2N}\right)$$

and here it is reproduced manually, for example for the third harmonic:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.fft import fft, dct

y = np.array([10,3,5])

# dct() call:
print(dct(y, 2))

# manual reproduction for k = 2:
N = 3
k = 2
n = np.array([0,1,2])
2 * (
    y[0] * np.cos((np.pi*k*(2*n[0]+1))/(2*N)) + 
    y[1] * np.cos((np.pi*k*(2*n[1]+1))/(2*N)) + 
    y[2] * np.cos((np.pi*k*(2*n[2]+1))/(2*N)))
```

in both cases I get a 9.

But there is no documentation for the 2D DCT, and my attempts at hacking the formula with a toy matrix are not working out:

Compare:

```
z = np.array([[ 2,  3       ],
             [ 10, 15]])
dct(z, axis=0)  # dct() call
```

to for instance:

```
N = 2
M = 2
k = 0
l = 0
n = np.array([0,1])
m = np.array([0,1])
M*N * (
    z[0,0] * np.cos((np.pi*k*(2*n[0]+1))/(2*N)) * np.cos((np.pi*l*(2*m[0]+1))/(2*M)) + 
    z[0,1] * np.cos((np.pi*k*(2*n[0]+1))/(2*N)) * np.cos((np.pi*l*(2*m[1]+1))/(2*M)) +
    z[1,0] * np.cos((np.pi*k*(2*n[1]+1))/(2*N)) * np.cos((np.pi*l*(2*m[0]+1))/(2*M)) +
    z[1,1] * np.cos((np.pi*k*(2*n[1]+1))/(2*N)) * np.cos((np.pi*l*(2*m[1]+1))/(2*M))
)
```

for the first coefficient.

Can anyone help me reconcile the output of `dct()` with my attempted manual calculation?

I guess the formula is not...

$$y_{k,l}= 4 \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\sum_{m=0}^{M-1}x_n y_m \cos \left( \frac{\pi k(2n + 1)}{2N}\right)\cos \left( \frac{\pi l(2m + 1)}{2M}\right)$$

but it would be really easy to correct if I could get the same output manually for one of the coefficients on the example matrix above.

The methods applied [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/10606/57249) make explicit reference to this author, but they don't help me understand what the function is doing.

---

PS The formula turns out to be spot on if it is called twice as in:

`dct(dct(z.T, axis=0).T, axis=0)`

Comment: Don't you just apply the DCT in one dimension, then again in the other?

Answer (score 1):

I'd take bets that the 2D-DCT is just separable into identical row-wise and column-wise DCTs. Anything else would be surprising.

Anyways, you know the 2D-DCT is a reversible linear operation: It maintains dimensionality, and has only a trivial null space. Therefore,  you can analyze what it does directly from applying it to an arbitrarily chosen basis of your matrix space.

Comment: Do you mean in your last paragraph that applying the `dct()` call twice to the identity matrix as in `dct(dct(np.eye(4).T, axis=0).T, axis=0)` would make sense? What could I learn from it?

Comment: You want to learn what a linear operator (the 2D DFT) does. So, do what you'd do to figure that out: Test it on a set of vectors that form a base.