# Fast DCT from DFT

Tags: fft, dft, dct

I need to compute the DCT of a signal (in fact its a image). As I already have the DFT of that signal, I wonder if there is any cheap way to obtain the DCT in terms of the DFT.

Note that I am not asking if the DCT can be computed via the FFT, which [has been answered here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2807/fast-cosine-transform-via-fft). The answers in the cited question perform modifications in the time domain. I have the additional constrain of "The FFT has been already computed with the input signal".

Obviously the task is possible in `O(N²)` time, because both transforms are orthonormal bases, so a possible way could be computing the transform matrix from one base to the other. This could be improved with `dct(ifft(x))`, where both operations have O(n log(n)) complexity.

Therefore, the question is if there is any linear time complexity algorithm that obtains the DCT of a signal from the Discrete Fourier Transform of that signal.

Comment: Is the DFT of "equal size" to the given signals / images? (e.g, given an 64x64 image, is the available DFT of size 64x64 too? )

Comment: No, I do not store the symmetric part of the DFT. Therefore, the DFT has size 64x33. In any case, calculating the missing half is trivial.

Comment: If you are not storing the symmetric part, then that should have been a 32x32 matrix. Can you please talk a little bit more about the application you are dealing with?

Comment: The application would be fast image comparisons (comparing just the lower frequencies). I was getting better results using the DCT, but its computation its being a bottleneck. No, the FFT would have 64x33, it is symmetrical on a diagonal, so if it were 32x32 you'd throw away half of the information